# Implement Django SetPasswordForm

Tags: python, django, forms

The Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms

I'm getting an error in my code below. `tuple' object has no attribute 'get'`

```
def password_reset(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SetPasswordForm(request.user)
        #Form.is_valid() is returning an error
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do this
        else:
            return (request, 'home/reset_password.html', {'form': form})
    form = SetPasswordForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'home/reset_password.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Show the _full_ stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `form = SetPasswordForm(request.user)`, you should use `form = SetPasswordForm(request.user, request.POST)`. Because you need to pass the values from the user whom sent the data via POST method, they are available in `request.POST`. You can check the implementation in [GitHub source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L336).

Comment: yep, I just noticed that in the source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L336

Comment: Yes, saw your edit which is why I deleted that :) anyway the error appears to be related to something else. Perhaps OP doesn't import the correct form or just creates a form with the same name and uses that?